# Does the compiler continue evaluating an expression where all must be true if the first is false?

Tags: c#, .net, boolean-logic

I'm sure this question has probably been answered before, so I apologize, but I wasn't able to find the proper search terms to find the answer.

Given the following code example, does `db.GetRecords().Any()` get executed?

```
string s = "Z";
bool x = s.IndexOfAny(new[] { 'A', 'B' }) > 0 &&
         db.GetRecords().Any();
```

Comment: You could try that out with some simpler function and you would get your answer.

Comment: @Gunner Good point. I should have thought of that. I guess not enough coffee yet this morning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. Both `&&` and `||` are evaluated by [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). This means that `a && b` returns false if `a` is false and `a || b` returns true if `a` is true and it will not evaluate `b` in either of these cases.

If for some reason you do not want short-circuit evaluation you can use the bitwise operators `&` and `|`.

Comment: Is there actually any good reason to use the singular & and | ?

Comment: @eddy56 & and | are often use to evaluate flags where multiple flags can be set.

Answer (score 3):

No. The `&&` operator short-circuits (which means it stops evaluating the expression after any part of the expression evaluates to false).

The `||` operator also short-circuits but stops evaluating after any part of the expression evaluates to true.

Comment: `||` does not stop evaluating when it detects an argument that is false.

Comment: @Malfist: I don't need one. You're telling me that `false || true` should evaluate to `false`?

Comment: @Jason Wow. Made a quick edit and obviously didn't think about what I was typing. Rolled back. ...need more coffee.

Answer (score 2):

No, C# use short circuit and. So the answer is **no**.

If you need to evaluate both, use NON-SHORT-CIRCUIT operator by using just one ampersand **&**.

```
tring s = "Z";
bool x = s.IndexOfAny(new[] { 'A', 'B' }) > 0 &
         db.GetRecords().Any();
```

Please note the single **&**.

Answer (score 2):

No

> [The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I say that for a C# logic-AND ([`&&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk(VS.71).aspx)), the second that an expression is false, since they all need to be true for the expression to be true, the compiler stops evaluating immediately.

> [**&& Operator (C# Reference)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk(v=VS.100).aspx)
>
> The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary.

Contrarely to a logic-AND, the logic-OR ([`||`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346(v=VS.80).aspx)) only requires only one expression among all to be true, for the whole expression to be true. So, instead of short-circuiting over a `false` evaluation, the `||` operator causes the compiler to short-circuit over a true evaluation.

> **[|| Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346(v=VS.80).aspx)**

Now, that is the behaviour of the C# compiler, but it doesn't mean every compiler bahves that way, as in VB.NET, you have two logic-AND operators ([`And`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh.aspx), [`AndAlso`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz(v=VS.100).aspx)), and two logic-OR operators (`Or`, `OrElse`). The `And` operator, used for both bitwise and logic conjunctions, does not short-circuit when the first expression returns false and evaluate the other anyway, while `AndAlso` will short-circuit the evaluation when the first logical expression is false. That is the same with `Or` and `OrElse`, where `Or` doesn't short-circuit, and `OrElse` does.

> **[And Operator (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh.aspx)**
>
> Performs a logical conjunction on two Boolean expressions, or a bitwise conjunction on two numeric expressions.
>
> [**AndAlso Operator (Visual Basic)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz(v=VS.100).aspx)
>
> Performs short-circuiting logical conjunction on two expressions.
>
> [**Or Operator (Visual Basic)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06s37a7f.aspx)
>
> Performs a logical disjunction on two Boolean expressions, or a bitwise disjunction on two numeric expressions.
>
> **[OrElse Operator (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx)**
>
> Performs short-circuiting inclusive logical disjunction on two expressions.

In short, I would say that this depends on the compiler you're working with. As for C#, it does short-circuit.

Answer (score 1):

It is shortcircuiting and allows you to do things like this:

```
if(ob && ob.somefunc()) { ... }
```

if both operations were evaluated, there would be a possibility of referencing a null object, which would be a runtime exception.

Comment: I think you mean `if (ob != null && ..` since the only way that would work is ob was a bool and bools don't really have methods unless you created somefunc to be an extension method which at that point it doesn't necessarily matter if ob is defined or not.