# boolean operation on methods

Tags: c#, boolean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the compiler continue evaluating an expression where all must be true if the first is false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997612/does-the-compiler-continue-evaluating-an-expression-where-all-must-be-true-if-th)
>   [Difference between eager operation and short-circuit operation? (| versu || and & versu &&)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838171/difference-between-eager-operation-and-short-circuit-operation-versu-and)

So here's my question.  If I have this

```
if (Foo() && Bar())
    DoStuff();
```

if Foo() returns false, will it still run through Bar()?  or do I need to have

```
if (Foo())
    if (Bar())
        DoStuff();
```

to ensure that it only runs through the minimum amount needed before "failing out"?

Comment: Good question, you could set a breakpoint in `Bar()` to see if it is hit during this check.

Comment: This has been asked perhaps, 100 times before. Please do some due diligence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (Foo() && Bar())
```

In this case (logical AND) it will firstly check `Foo()` return value and will do `Bar()` only if `Foo()` returns true. Simply if any of conditions is false then it will not check others, it will check conditions from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

No, `Bar()` won't be evaluated if `Foo()` returns false. It's a feature of the C# `&&` operator (not limited to `if` statements):

> The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called "Short-circuiting," and yes, [.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) supports it.

Comment: and in _VB.NET_ the keyword is `AndAlso` for `&&`, and `OrElse` for `||`.

Comment: I hadn't heard of short-circuiting before, thanks for pointing it out.